# SQL query: need help on subquery

Tags: sql, database, join, subquery

Question is as follows:

There are 2 related tables (am giving some sample values for making it simplified):

```
Circuit
--------
id    name
1      a
2      b
3      c

Circuit_Dependent
-----------------
id    depend_id
1     2
1     3
```

the tables are related and second table tells the relation with the circuit id's.
Situation is query needed for:
1) list the circuit name which has the circuit_dependency
output expected:

```
name   dependent_name
a      b
a      c
```

2) list the circuit name and count(no of dependancies)
output expected:

```
name   count
a      2
```

appreciate help.

Comment: if this is a home work please add appropriate tag

Comment: this was one of the interview question asked.

Comment: I hope you aren't using the answers here for a job interview - seems pretty shady.

Comment: no way... i have posted the question AFTER my interview and I wanted to know the answer so that I can prepare well for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First query could be:

```
SELECT c1.`name`, c2.`name`
FROM Circuit_Dependent cd INNER JOIN Circuit c1 
    ON cd.id = c1.id    
INNER JOIN Circuit c2 
    ON cd.depend_id = c2.id
```

Second query could be this one:

```
SELECT c.`name`, COUNT(DISTINCT cd.depend_id) AS count 
FROM circuit c INNER JOIN Circuit_Dependent cd
    ON c.id = cd.id
GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: I don't think your second query will execute, you can't reference a column in the select that's not part of the aggregate. (i.e. you select name, but it's not part of your group by nor an aggregate function)

Comment: @CAbbott: did you try it? Well, it works :) Anyway OP can change it with `GROUP BY c.name`. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm just going by SQL Server since the OP didn't specify the DB. :)

Comment: @CAbbott: oh, OK.. I'm using MySql for the same reason :)